# Sending SMS through android using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, sms

Can I use Firebase to deliver SMS messages without relying on any third-party libraries? Is there an API for sending SMS messages in Firebase? cause I looked over the Firebase website and the net but couldn't find those details only notification messages are popping out. If not, is there a free third-party API that can be used? Suggestions and comments are always appreciated.